# Shading a Sphere using Gouraud Shading

Tags: opengl

I am trying to shade a sphere. I calculated the normals to each vertex of the sphere, but I don't understand how the other pixels on the facets will be shaded. Any help on this ? I am using OpenGL 3+.

Comment: Show us your code and your problem. Basically the colors computed at the corners will simply be interpolated over the surface.

Comment: "I don't understand how the other pixels on the facets will be shaded." How do you want them to be shaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gouraud shading the lighting model is computed (as a color) for each vertex of the triangle and then linearly interpolated over the triangle pixels.

In OpenGL you simply compute the ligthting model for each vertex in a vertex shader as a color vector passed to a fragment shader as a varying and then the linear interpolation is done automatically "for free".

If you want Phong shading, you pass the vertex normal directly to the fragment shader which will be automatically linearly interpolated too and then you compute the lighting model in the fragment shader using this interpolated normal.

Comment: this is what I dont get >> "the linear interpolation is done automatically "for free"." So basically for shading, I don't mess with the main code, I just have to edit the *.vert and *.frag files ?

Comment: The only way to disable this interpolation is to enable glShadeModel(GL_FLAT) with older OpenGL compatibility profile. And no, you can do all in shaders except of above.